# Find and Click cell by inner html string inside table Webbrowser

Tags: vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am trying to find string in column 1 and automatically click "detail" in column 3..

```
|-----------------------------------------|
| Column 1    | Column 2    | Column 3    |
|-----------------------------------------|
| David       | 12345       | detail      |
| Jhon        | 67890       | detail      |
| Ester       | 67890       | detail      |
```

Until recently I could only find the words in column 1 using this code :

```
    Dim tables As HtmlElementCollection = Me.WebBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("table")
    For Each tbl As HtmlElement In tables
        For Each row As HtmlElement In tbl.All
            For Each cell As HtmlElement In row.All
                If Not cell.Style Is Nothing Then
                    If cell.InnerText.Contains("Jhon") Then
                        cell.InvokeMember("click") '---Not working because "Jhon" is not Hyperlink.
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
```

Now I have to find ways to click on the word detail in column 3.. is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've found the cell you're looking for just iterate the rest of the cells in that row until you find the *"detail"* cell.

```
If cell.InnerText.Contains("Jhon") Then
    For Each rcell As HtmlElement In row.All
        If rcell.InnerHtml.Contains("detail") Then
            rcell.InvokeMember("click")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Alternatively, if clicking the cell itself does not work, click the first `a` tag:

```
If cell.InnerText.Contains("Jhon") Then
    For Each rcell As HtmlElement In row.All
        If rcell.InnerHtml.Contains("detail") Then
            Dim tags As HtmlElementCollection = rcell.GetElementsByTagName("a")
            If tags.Length > 0 Then
                tags(0).InvokeMember("click")
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End If
```

Comment: i use your main solution, but its not working.. then i change your code  "For Each rcell As HtmlElement In row.all" to "For Each rcell In row.all" and "rcell.InnerText.Contains("detail")" to "rcell.InnerText("detail")".. its working now.. thanks anyway.. am i have to mark your answer?

Comment: @CrazyThink : If I may be honest your changes does not make much sense. Your first change does not make any difference, and the second should not even compile. Changing my code from `InnerText` to `InnerHtml` could work though. -- If it worked then I suggest you mark it as the accepted answer, yes. This can be done by pressing the check mark on the left of my answer.

Comment: @CrazyThink : I changed `InnerText` to `InnerHtml` in my answer.